# Load Image while generating a PDF using Flying Saucer

Tags: html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I am using following code to generate PDF using CSS now I am using inline CSS because I am not able to load CSS externally.

```
File file = new File(path + "\\" + id + "\\" + fileName + ".pdf");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        StringBuilder htmls = new StringBuilder();
        htmls.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        htmls.append("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
        htmls.append("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
        /*htmls.append("<head><style type=\"text/css\">");
        htmls.append("body{text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px;}");
        htmls.append("</style></head>");*/
        htmls.append("<head><style type=\"text/css\">");
        htmls.append(".gradi{background:url(resources/template/template1/images/grad.jpg) repeat-x!important}");
        htmls.append("</style></head>");
        htmls.append("<body>html body</body></html>");
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmls.toString());
            renderer.layout();
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
            renderer.createPDF(fos);
```

Now problem with above code is that I am using the `setDocumentFromString` function so I can not load CSS externally.

All of my images are in folder "resources/template/template1/images". Is there any way that I can load images in my servlet?

What path I should give in following line of CSS to load image? please help me to solve this issue.

```
htmls.append(".gradi{background:url(resources/template/template1/images/grad.jpg) repeat-x!important}");
```